# Flutter run did not able able execute a lot of files and keep asking for permission

Tags: flutter

I upgraded to flutter `3.7.9`. There were some issues related to file permission and I resolved them. Now I am able to create an app using both in command line `flutter create aap-name` and also by going to android studio.

But when I try to run using command line `flutter run` or in android studio I see a lot of files not have permission to execute.

```
Permission denied
flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/bottom_navigation_bar.dart to execute .pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/vector_math-2.1.4/lib/vector_math_64.dart
```

I tried to give permission to the file to execute but it keep asking one after another.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was when the `.pub-cache` file was created by `flutter pub get` it created few of the folder inside `.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/` as `root` user file. Strange that it did not do to all file but only to some. Some files still had the user level permission.

As I was logged in as user ( not root), the user did not able to execute these files and it will throwing error for all the files which owned by root.

Below is the steps to solve it

- Open terminal
- Login as root user by `su -`
- go to the `.pub-cache/hosted` folder
- run `sudo chown yourusername: pub.dev/*` to change the ownership of the all sub folder and files to current user

Answer (score 1):

after trying all method, changing owner all folder worked for my on my air m1,

```
sudo chown -R yourusername ~
```